# Getting [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:install-node-and-npm even after updating to the latest version

Tags: node.js, maven

This is a known error for this artifact.

https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/565

And the solution is to update to the latest version.

But even after using the latest version I'm still getting the same error.

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project: Could not download Node.js from: https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.40/x64/node.exe: Got error code 503 from the server. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.